# Does it make sense to use a reference in this case?

Tags: c++

I wonder if it makes sense to use references when using literal constants.
Below i made a few examples:

```cpp
bool funcWithoutReference(const std::string Text)
{
    return Text == "Hello!";
}

bool funcWithReference(const std::string& Text)
{
    return Text == "Hello!";
}

int main()
{
    // Example 1: Average execution time: 13.652 sec
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        std::string text = "Hello";
        funcWithoutReference(text);
    }

    // Example 2: Average execution time: 7.283 sec
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        funcWithoutReference("Hello");
    }

    // Example 3: Average execution time: 7.249 sec
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        std::string text = "Hello";
        funcWithReference(text);
    }

    // Example 4: Average execution time: 7.292 sec
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        funcWithReference("Hello");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why is there such a difference between examples 1 and 2? I understand that using a literal constant in memory a "temporary" variable is created and passed as a parameter to the function. But why does example 2 get results almost like 3 and 4? Is a copy only made when we pass a variable as a parameter?

Time was measured as standard, using clock_t.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Examples 2, 3, and 4 are identical. In all cases, you construct a `std::string` initialized with "Hello" for every iteration of the loop. In Example 1, you do this but also copy it. If you want your function to work fast with string literals, consider using [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view) as the argument: https://godbolt.org/z/15KTr8db1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples 2, 3, and 4 are identical. In each, you create a single `std::string` per loop iteration. Example 1 does this too, but also copies it.

Let's break it down...

### Example 1

Total string objects: 2

```
std::string text = "Hello";
funcWithoutReference(text);
```

Every time around the loop, you create a new string, initialized from the literal `"Hello"`. You then pass it by value, so it is copied as a result of the function call.

### Example 2

Total string objects: 1

```
funcWithoutReference("Hello");
```

Every time around the loop, you create a temporary string, initialized from the literal `"Hello"`. This happens as a result of resolving the function call that will implicitly convert the literal to a `std::string` by way of one of its available constructors. This string is an *rvalue*, meaning a temporary result. It only exists for the duration of the function call.

### Example 3

Total string objects: 1

```
std::string text = "Hello";
funcWithReference(text);
```

Every time around the loop, you create a new string, initialized from the literal `"Hello"`. You then pass this by reference, so no additional copies are made.

### Example 4

Total string objects: 1

```
funcWithReference("Hello");
```

Every time around the loop, you create a temporary string, initialized from the literal `"Hello"`. This happens as a result of resolving the function call that requires a `const std::string&`. To achieve that, the literal is first implicitly converted to a `std::string` *rvalue* by way of one of its available constructors. That is then provided by reference.

### Notes

It should be pointed out that your test might be a bit bogus. These loops have no actual side-effects, and could potentially be optimized away completely. And Example 1 could also be optimized to elide the copy because there is no other use or side-effect for the local string.

### Improvement

To avoid the overhead of allocating a new `std::string`, you may choose to use [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view) (since C++17). This is a light-weight string-like interface that works on both literals and `std::string`. It does not do any dynamic allocation.

The cost of copying a string_view is therefore very low so you can pass them by value or reference without incurring a significant difference in computational cost.

```
#include <string_view>

bool funcWithoutReference(std::string_view Text)
{
    return Text == "Hello!";
}

bool funcWithReference(const std::string_view& Text)
{
    return Text == "Hello!";
}

int main()
{
    // No allocation per iteration
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        funcWithoutReference("Hello");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        funcWithReference("Hello");
    }

    // Single allocation per iteration
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        funcWithoutReference(std::string{"Hello"});
    }

    // Single allocation per iteration
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        funcWithReference(std::string{"Hello"});
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! In the second example, I was wondering if a copy was being created, but after the results it immediately fell out of my head, so I asked a question as well.

Comment: Yeah, in that case there's no point creating a temporary and then copying it because the temporary _is_ the "copy", created purely to fulfill the need of providing the correct type conversion. I'm sure that basic behavior will be strictly specified in the language spec somewhere, but no way am I gonna dig through that.